Flaskで構築したWEBアプリケーションでFORM POSTから10,000行程度の文字列を受け取ろうとする際の容量制限エラーの回避方法について教えて頂きたいです。
当方初学者で初質問ですので、至らない点がありましたらご容赦ください。
現在Flaskで自作のWEBアプリケーションを制作しているのですが、POSTで大量のテキスト入力を受け付けさせようとするとブラウザ側で下記のエラー表示が出てしまいます。
Request Entity Too Large
The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.
ネットで調べたところ、configをpythonファイル側に記述することでPOSTで受け取るデータの容量制限を設定できるとのことだったのですが、どうもうまくいきません、
※下記例では1MBと認識しています。
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024
やりたいこととしては、textareaにNW機器のログ等を10,000行程度のテキストで受け取り、それをPython側で処理するというものです。
試しているログのデータは10,000行、およそ600,000文字になります。
環境としましては
Python 3.12.7
Flask 3.0.3
WEBサーバーはFlask組み込みのものです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

これらの記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。Flask フォームデータ最大サイズ設定, 413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE flask werkzeug gunicorn MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH, How to handle "413: Request Entity Too Large" in python flask server

1024 * 1024 * 1024だと 1GBでは？

MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH はファイルサイズを指定するので、試しているログのデータも文字数や行数ではなくファイルサイズでどの程度必要となるのかを見積もった方が良さそうです。

@kunif　ありがとうございます。ご紹介頂きましたリンク参照したところ、Flaskのrequestの制限のようなので、参考にしながらコード修正して解決できそうです。ありがとうございました。

@oriri 初歩的過ぎて恥ずかしいミスです。穴があったら入りたいです、、。

@cubick　ファイルサイズとしては500KB程度と見積もっていますが、HTTPではなくFlaskのrequestのハードコードによる制約のようなので別のアプローチを試してみます。ありがとうございました。
